# How to display data on a jsp page from a modelview?

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I want to print data from a modelview onto a jsp page, but it tells:

> property["all properties"] not found at java.lang.string!

This is code in my jsp page:

```
<c:forEach items="{$lRetailers}" var="retailerview">
<tr>
<td>"${retailerview.business_name}"</td>
<td>"${retailerview.city}"</td>
<td>${retailerview.startDate}</td>
<td>${retailerview.status}</td>
<td>${retailerview.url}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
  </table>
```

This code is of controller:

```
@GetMapping("/retailer/view")
public ModelAndView  getAllRetailers()
{
    ModelAndView mav= new ModelAndView("retailerview");
    List<Retailer> lRetailers= repository.findAll();
    System.out.println("Retailer" +lRetailers.toString());
    mav.addObject("retailerview",lRetailers);
    return mav;
}
```

This is bean class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="retailer")
public class Retailer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "UUID",
    strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
)
@Column(name = "retailer_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)

private UUID id;

@Column(name="businessName")
private String businessName;

@Column(name="startDate")
private String startDate;

@Column(name="city")
private String City;

@Column(name="status")
private String isActive;

@Column(name="url")
private String url;
getter and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JSP: `items="{$lRetailers}"` should be `items="${lRetailers}"`

and in your controller:

`mav.addObject("retailerview",lRetailers);` should be 
`mav.addObject("lRetailers",lRetailers);`

Comment: Thanks,it helped me resolve the error..but now it still dosen't dispaly any data!!

Comment: Does the collection contain anyhing?